# Finding Specific Text Records

Tags: ms-access

I am working on a project with a table having a text field as its Primary Key.  On on form, I have the [Name] listed in a list of items and want to open the corresponding record to that specific text record.  Here is what I am looking at:

[image: Main Form]

[image: Form to display selected record]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Sincerely,

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will open a form with the Muscles button:

1. Open Properties on the Muscles button and go to the On Click event on the Event tab. Click the three dots and choose Code Builder.
2. Add the following code (change frmMuscles to the name of the form you are opening, MuscleName to the name of the field, and sfrmMuscles to the name of the subform):

docmd.OpenForm "frmMuscles",,,"MuscleName='" & me.sfrmMuscles.MuscleName.Value & "'"

Note that you need to point to the subform that has the name of the muscle desired to be opened and it needs to be surrounded by single quotes which are placed inside of double quotes.

This will give you a GO TO combo box:

Using the combo box wizard will get you most of the way there. And then you just edit the macro with a small change.

1. Start by deleting your Go To and combo box.
2. Grab a combo box off the tool bar and add it to your header. When you do that, you should get a combo box wizard that offers three options: pull from a table, add your own entries, or find a record on your form. Select the third option. (You can put the combo box in the body of your form and still get the third option but I like it in the header.)
3. Go through the wizard and select your key field. Type in Go To: as the label of your combo box.
4. This may be all you need for your preference. Try it out. My problem is that the combo box stays filled and if you move to a different record, the combo box does not update automatically. So instead, I edit the query and set the value of the combo box to blank (I would use 0 if it was a number field).
5. To edit the macro, open the properties of your combo box and choose the Event tab. There is an embedded macro on the After Update Event. Click on the embedded macro and click the three dots to the right to edit the macro.
6. Once the macro opens, you have a SearchForRecord option at the top. Under it, there is an "Add New Action" drop-down.
7. In the "Add New Action", select SetProperty. That will open and allow you to enter values that you want to use.
8. For Control Name, select the name of your combo box. If you don't know, the name is displayed in the tab at the top. For Property, select Value. Then in Value, enter "". This will blank the combo box. Click Close at the top and you will be asked to Save.

This should give you a combo box that moves to the selected record and then blanks out the combo box.

Comment: Thank you for the response to my issue.  However, this is not quite what I was looking for.  The function you are suggesting is featured in the "Go To:" combo box.  I'm looking for the "Muscles" button to open the active record from the subform it is assigned to.  So, given my example above the button should open the Muscle form filtered to Rectus Abdominis.  For some reason, I am unable to get a filter to work or the where conditions and I know it has to be due to the text field lookup instead of a numeric lookup.  Any suggestions.  Thank you!

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for.  However, I get a compiler error the the "Method or data member not found" for the subform name.  Here is what I am putting:  DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Muscles" , , , "Name = ' " & Me.frm_Exercises_Muscles_Subform.Name.Value & " ' "  Am I entering the command wrong?  I've verified the field names and form names but still getting the error.  I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Sorry it has taken me so long to respond. When a form is opened, the subforms on it also open. There should be no reason to open a subform.